# Proof by contradiction that an open interval in $\mathbb{R}$ is path-connected if it is connected

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification

I am trying to prove, by contradiction, that an open interval in $\mathbb{R}$ is path-connected if it is connected. Is the following correct?

Consider an arbitrary open and connected interval $\mathbb (a,b)\subset \mathbb{R} $. Suppose, for a contradiction, that $(a,b)$ is not path-connected. Consider an arbitrary pair of points which cannot be connected by any path, $x, y$ (where, wlog, $y>x$). Note that $(a,b)$ can be written as $(a,x) \cup [x,y]\cup (y,b)$. Also, note that $[x,y] \not\subset  (a,b)$ (as otherwise there would exist a path connecting $x$ and $y$: namely, $f(t)=ty+(1-t)x$).

Thus, there must exist a subset of $[a,b]$, $\Pi$, such that $(a,b)=(a,x) \cup  \Pi\cup (y,b)$. Note that $\Pi$ cannot be formed by removing either of $x$ or $y$ from $[x,y]$, as, by assumption, both points belong to $(a,b)$. Thus, $\Pi$ must be of the form $[a,z_1]\cup[z_2, b]$, for some  $z_1, z_2 \in (a,b)$, $z_2 >z_1$. So then $(a,b)=(a,x) \cup [x,z_1] \cup [z_2, y] \cup (y, b)=(a,z_1] \cup [z_2, b)$.

Finally, realise that the sets in $(a,z_1] \cup [z_2, b)$ are each (1) disjoint from the other; and (2) open in $(a,b)$. Thus, $(a,b)$ can be written as the union of two disjoint sets that are each open in $(a,b)$. This contradicts the assumption that $(a,b)$ is connected.

Thank you.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier a direct proof instead of conttradiction?

Comment: @TitoEliatron I had attempted this in my second most recent post, but was advised to approach it by contradiction instead.

Comment: Ok, then.......

Comment: I am slightly confused. Why does the question talk a priori about _intervals_ when the whole point of the exercise is to show that connected open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are exactly the intervals?

Comment: Also the conclusion "Thus, $\Pi$ must be of the form $[a,z_1]\cup[z_2,b]$" is a bit out of nowhere. Why can't $\Pi$ be a cantor set, or a Vitali set, or something different? The only thing you do know that some point $c$ with $x<c<y$ is not in $(a,b)$. (But then again, because per definition of interval $(a,b)=\{p\in\mathbb{R}\colon a<p<b\}$, we know already that $c\in(a,b)$ )

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your previous post, I believe you want to prove the following statement for a connected set $S\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ by contradiction:

$$\forall a,b\in S,\forall c\in\mathbb{R}, a<c<b\Rightarrow c\in S.$$

Which can be shown by assuming there are some $a,b\in S$ and $c\in\mathbb{R}\setminus S$ with $a<c<b$ and concluding that then $\Big((-\infty,c)\cup(c,\infty)\Big)\cap S=S$ is not connected.

Once you have shown this, the rest can be done directly:

Given a connected set $S$ and two points $a,b\in S$ with $a\le b$ we can take the path $\gamma\colon[0,1]\to S$ by $\gamma(t)=(1-t)a+tb$. Because $a\le\gamma(t)\le b$ we know that $\gamma(t)\in S$ by the previous.